# In a compact metric space, a sequence with a certain property is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness

The question:

Let $(K,d)$ be a compact metric space, if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence such that $\{d(x_n,x)\}$ converges for all $x \in K$, then $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence.

My attempt:

Notice that we can define for each $n$, $f_n(x)=d(x_n,x)$, this is an isometry and thus these are equicontinuous functions.

Also, each converging sequence gives us the fact that these functions are pointwise bounded.

Thus we can us Arzela-Ascoli Therom to show that in fact the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ has a unifromly convergent subsequence.

Now if I can show that their limit is indeed of the form $f(x)=d(a,x)$ for some $a\in K$, then I can show that $a$ is the limit of the sequence, but I don't know how to do it or even if it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges, it has subsequences $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and $(x_{m_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ with distinct limits, $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively. The fact that it has a convergent subsequence whose limit is some $l_1$ follows from the compacity of $K$. Since the sequence diverges, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such $d(x_k,l_1)\geqslant\varepsilon$ for infinitely many $k$'s. And from those $x_k$'s you can extract another convergent subsequence, again by the compacity of $K$.

But then the sequence $\bigl(d(x_n,l_1)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges, since it has a subsequence whose limit is $0$ and another subsequence whose limit is $d(l_1,l_2)$.

Comment: Is $n$ overloaded here?

Comment: @JairTaylor Not anymore. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for the answer! However I am a little curious that if my claim in the last part of my attempt is true, could you maybe consider that a little?

Comment: @StAKmod I don't see how to prove that a uniformly convergent subsequence of that sequence of functions must have a limit of the form $x\mapsto d(a,x)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I had an idea, which is to determine all the possible forms of isometries from $K$ to $C(K)$, but I have no idea how to implement that idea. Anyway thanks for the nice solution!